# decode javascript sequence into python

Tags: javascript, python, decode

I'm a beginner to Python trying to decode this javascript sequence. I'm not only a beginner in Python, I understand javascript even less :) I know i could put it into an online decoder such as this: http://coderstoolbox.net/string/ but I want to deal with it myself - more for practice than anything else... Im using Beautiful Soup to get the data, so I have its functions available for decoding.

If anyone can point me to equivalent functions in python I would appreciate it.

```
function encode(str){
 var t=''; var s=unescape(str);
 var x=Math.round(Math.sqrt(49));
 for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++) t+=
  String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i)^(i%2?x:0));
 print(t);
}
```

This is my understanding of it so far:

1. i think I can use 'HTML entities in BS to unescape..?
2. the second one just seems to be a constant number ? square root of 49 rounded...
3. sets up the loop
4. this is the one i dont get. 1 i dont know what the fromCharCode function does. 2 not sure what the bit at the end is. looks like its getting a character code from i to the power something. i understand i is being modulo'd with 2 but what is the '?x:0' bit ? - how would you replicate this in Python ?

thanks for reading !

EDIT: is there a python library that can just run this code ? I've done this before with bash and used rhino, but the alternatives in Python seem a bit scary for a beginner, eg spidermonkey, etc...

Comment: `a?b:c` is a conditional expression: if `a` is true, the value of the expression is `b`, otherwise it's `c`. In Python it's `b if a else c`. Notice the difference in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) the python equivalent to unescape is [urllib.unquote()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) in python 2.x series and [urllib.parse.unquote()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) in python 3.x series

2) you guess the simplest way to do it is to do `x = 7`

3) the simplest way to loop on string charters is to do `for c in string:` but to have the index you should do `for i,c in enumerate(string):`

4) the string.charChodeAt(c) is the same than chr(c)

finally I would duplicate the loop part as follow:

```
result = []
for i,c in enumerate(string):
    result.append(chr(ord(c)^(x if i%2 else 0)))
print("".join(result))
```

in fact using a temporary array to make the appends is more efficient than happening to strings as the strings don't mutate

Comment: oh, now i dont know who to mark as correct :) sorry you came along just about 1 second too late :) many many thanks dude

Comment: in this case, everyones correct :) although your answer is the more comprehensive for what im after. thanks again.

Comment: ok done, someone deleted me saying 'hahah ok', wow, some anal dudes on here.

Comment: in fact you can't have too short comments it's for readability

Comment: apart from the stray semi colon that works perfectly, many many thanks, i wouldnt have figured that out on my own.

Comment: the semi column bug is what happen when you don't test the code

Comment: if only I could install you on my shoulder :) *massive hug* for sorting me out! even though Im actually an automated bot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python, but I can explain what is happening here so that you can rewrite in Python.

1) function encode is declared and not assigned, so in JavaScript it will get hoisted to the top of its parent function, if there is one.

2) Inside function encode there are 4 variables that will get hoisted to the top of function encode:

- t, which is assigned to an empty string, which means 0 length but type is string
- s, which is assigned of a value of the argument "str" that is passed through the unencode function.  unencode just reverses a URI reserved character encoding.
- x, which is of type number with a value of 7
- i, which is assigned 0 and used as your loop iterator

3) The loop index starts at 0 and breaks no later than the index is the same size as the character length on variable s.

4) The loop is written in a sloppy manner without curly braces, so it terminates at the first line break, which means variable t is performing a string concat in reflection of variable s.

5) The next line beginning with the string object looks like it is supposed to be in loop, but its not, because this code is sloppy.  It doesn't matter anyways because variable s is not really used for anything further.

6) A print function is used with variable t as its argument.  Variable t should look identical to variable s, which is probably not what the original author of this code intended.

7) I have no idea what print is.  Perhaps the original author meant something like alert or console.log instead of print.

Comment: wow, thanks! :))) i changed the document.write to print on 7) just to output the text. ah yes i thought that was a bit weird that "t+=
  String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i)^(i%2?x:0));" bit. so are you are saying the math bit doesnt do anything at all ? its just unescaping ?

Comment: Yes.  Use curly braces for loops and conditions.  for (blah) {code in here}, because right now the only thing in that loop is "t+=" and nothing further.

Comment: wow, ok, thats pretty sloppy. so i just need to unescape this string once i figure out how to extract it out of the html :) many thanks mate.

Comment: in fact the s is used in s.charCodeAt(i)

Comment: Its not assigned to anything and not returned, so while you technically correct its still a dead statement.

Comment: it is affected in the t+= line just above

Comment: The original code in that line is equivocal to t+=; due to the line break, and the next line neither updates variables t or s.

Comment: isn't that line making it append the charcode string to t ? well, just unescaping the string doesnt work, you need to do that charcode stuff to it as well, so it must be.

Comment: I guess it does.  I just ran proof in my console, so it seems the += operator is preventing semicolon insertion.  Its because of confusion like this that you should always use curly braces for loops and conditions.

Comment: luckily i dont use javascript :) seems like another world of pain, thanks for your detailed investigation, really helped a lot on speeding up my learning process. just books and obscurely written web pages dont cut it sometimes :)

Comment: JavaScript is not a world of pain if written in a well disciplined manner.  You just cannot be sloppy with it, because when you do it will do things contrary to your intentions.